# Semaphore has value 10. It will become 7 after

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, scheduling, semaphore

1. 3P operations
2. 13P and 10V operations.

These were two options among a few others in a question. Option 1 makes sense, and its marked as the correct answer. But then why not option 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

After 10P, the semaphore will block. Thus the remains won't be executed (unless some other process "helps" with V operations).